# How to prevent "SIte can't be reached" for others to view my repo of GitLab built in docker visible to me, with its URL which starts with my IP?

Tags: docker, gitlab, containers, ip, ip-address

I am fairly new to GitLab and had been asked to create a container for GitLab in Docker. The issue is that, even though my local directory that I pushed to GitLab is available to me, when I share it to others, they see are unable to view it. Please mind that, the URL of the repository is like http://192.***.**.***:1234/root/MyGitLabRepo.

I have ensured that my Docker & GitLab container is running properly on my system [(Proof)](https://imgur.com/a/0eJU8ie). Could the port that I have chosen (1234) be one of the reasons for why I can't share my repository?

In the 'Proof' linked above, my repository can also be seen working without any issue as when I use Git to push my local files to the GitLab repository, they get pushed without any problem. Please provide with a solution for how I can share my repository and if there is any detail that I missed, kindly let me know.

To fix this issue, I tried making sure my Docker & GitLab container were working fine. Though the repository is opening in my browser without any issue, when I try to open it on a different system, I get shown "this site took too long to load". I was expecting the repository that I had pushed to GitLab to open up when the shared URL was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by running the site on the same IP network or wifi as my own. The reason for why I was being shown "This site can't be reached" was due to the other computers not being connected to the same wifi.